# How to select each <li> with each button click sequentially using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

```
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Los Angeles</li>
  <li>Chicago</li>
</ul>
```

I start out by setting the click function to select the list items. The only problem is that it selects each one. I could use the **`eq()`** method, but that would not allow me to select each next list item every time the button is clicked. I tried the **`next()`** method and that does select the next item, but my question is, "How can I select the first list item when the button is clicked, then the next list item after the next click and so on.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('ul li').css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: you could add an active class to `<li>` on click and check for it

Comment: Adding an active class wouldn't allow me to cycle through the list items with each button click.

Comment: @Mark You can cycle through the list with a class too.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a selected class is about the easiest then you can traverse to `next()` or `first()` depending if the current selected is last in the group or not

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $items = $('li'),
    $selected = $items.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected'),
    $next;
  // first time only when no selected exists, remove if you automatically select first one
  if (!$selected.length) {
    $next = $items.first();
  } else {
    $next = $selected.is($items.last()) ? $items.first() : $selected.next();
  }

  $next.addClass('selected')
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Los Angeles</li>
  <li>Chicago</li>
</ul>
<button>Toggle selections</button>
```

Comment: Great! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'm still reading and learning. I guess it takes time to learn JavaScript and jQuery. A lot of time!

Comment: Like anything ... takes lots of practice and early stages are steep learning curve. Suggest you go to jQuery API and read through all the methods used here and see more examples of each

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully once I learn all the methods and start actually practicing writing code, I should start to develop a sense for tying elements together and manipulating the DOM with events, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a count. So, you would have a separate variable which verifies that this is the first click. If it is a first click, we select `.eq(0)` or `.first()`. If not, se always select `.next()`.

Let's take a look at how that would work in practice, on your example. HTML would stay the same, and JS would change:

```js
var alreadyClicked = false;
var selectedElement;

$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  if (alreadyClicked) {
    selectedElement = selectedElement.next();
  } else {
    alreadyClicked = true;
    selectedElement = $('ul li').first();
  }
  
  selectedElement.css('color', 'red');
  
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Los Angeles</li>
  <li>Chicago</li>
</ul>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
```

As you can see, we are keeping count inside the `alreadyClicked` boolean. If it is false, we will select the first element, otherwise, we always move up by one.

Additionally, we can improve the code by removing the `alreadyClicked` entirely, and just checking if `selectedElement` is already filled.

Comment: Only use demo links to support what actually exists in the answer. Link only answers are of little value

Comment: I mean....show your code in the answer and use demo link only  for additional support for that code

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. Actually the first example at the top of the page shows exactly what I was looking for. Setting a click function and selecting each list item and checking if the item has a class or not works perfectly. The code above doesn't cycle through each list item with each click event.

Comment: Whatever suits you :) it is my belief, that the simplest solution is always the best one, which i teach my students. The code snippet does in fact iterate through each single item within a loop. In other words, each time you click, a different item is selected. Most importantly, your code does not depend on classes, which, while indeed broadly used, is not the best possible practice, because it requires that you ensure that classes are not messed with by other functions/components. Doing it this way makes the function idempotent. Of course there is always room for improvement :) hope i helped

Answer (score 0):

Right at the top of my head you could add a `class`which you can reference when you click you're button.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    var selectedItem = null;
    if($('.is-selected').length) {
        if (!$('.is-selected').is('li:last')) {
          selectedItem = $('.is-selected').next();
        }
        $('.is-selected').removeClass('is-selected');
    }
    
    if (!selectedItem) {
       selectedItem = $('ul').children().first();
    }
    
    selectedItem.addClass('is-selected');
});
```

```css
.is-selected {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Los Angeles</li>
  <li>Chicago</li>
</ul>

<button type='button'>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: shouldn't be the case as its only selecting the children of the `ul` unless the `button` itself is inside the `ul`.

Comment: After the third element is selected and the button is click. It would have to go back to the top of the list.

Comment: @Mark I've changed the code so that it loops automatically instead of having to press the button again.

Comment: Now the code is working as I expected. Looks good! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <ul>
      <li>sdf</li>
      <li>sddsdfs</li>
    </ul>

    <button>Click</button>
```

JS:

```
var count=1;
var length = $('ul').children().length;
$('button').on('click', function(){
    count =( count ==length) ? 0: count;
    if(count>1 && count <= length){
  $('ul li:nth-child('+(count - 1)+')').css("color", "");
    $('ul li:nth-child('+count+')').css("color", "red");
  }
  else{
        $('ul li:nth-child('+count+')').css("color", "red");
  }
  count++;
})
```

You could do something like this.

Comment: You have a logic problem with `count`. You never decrement it when it reaches max

Comment: This code actually complicates matters. It's best to filter the selector and check to see if the selector has a class and then check if it's the first or the last in the list. The ternary operator works perfect for the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: The second code block that @fixatd provides works very well too. Thanks for all your input. It makes learning JavaScript or any programming language a pleasure. Thanks again!